# VBS Object required: '[string: ""]'

Tags: vbscript, runtime-error

I have the code

```
set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Offline = True
ie.Navigate "about:blank"
ie.Height     = 200
ie.Width      = 425
ie.MenuBar    = False
ie.StatusBar  = False
ie.AddressBar = False
ie.Toolbar    = False
ie.Visible = True
WshShell.Run "%windir%\notepad.exe"
WshShell.AppActivate "Notepad"
WScript.Sleep 3000
set a = WshShell.SendKeys("a") & Wscript.Sleep("100")
a
```

It does type "a" in notepad, but then it gives the error," Object Required: '[string: ""]' " and it will prevent any code after it from running.

If anyone knows how to fix this and prevent it in the future that would be great.

Comment: In VBScript you concatenate *commands* with `:`, not `&` (that is used to concatenate *strings*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to [assign something to a variable as an object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4afksd44) that isn't an object (`Set a = ...`). Don't do that. Neither `SendKeys()` nor `Sleep()` return output, so there's no point in assigning that non-output anyway. Or in concatenating it (you're probably confusing the VBScript [string concatenation operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx97884w) `&` with the batch command chaining operator `&`).

Change this:

```
Set a = WshShell.SendKeys("a") & WScript.Sleep("100")
```

into this:

```
WshShell.SendKeys("a")
WScript.Sleep(100)
```

and the problem will disappear.

---

If you're trying to implement a procedure that you can invoke as a shorthand, that would be done e.g. like this:

```
Sub k
  WshShell.SendKeys("a")
  WScript.Sleep(100)
End Sub

k  'sends keystroke "a" and waits 100 ms
```

or like this, if you want it parametrized:

```
Sub k(keys)
  WshShell.SendKeys(keys)
  WScript.Sleep(100)
End Sub

k "b"  'sends keystroke "b" and waits 100 ms
```

Comment: Typically I would do that, but what I'm trying to do with this script is make it so I could type the letter of the alphabet and it would output it then sleep for 100ms. This is so I can quickly do a sendkey and then sleep with the fewest characters needed for each letter.

Comment: What makes you think my suggested change wouldn't do exactly that? Or did you want to define a *procedure* that you could invoke to send a keystroke and then sleep 100ms?

Comment: I tried it out and a procedure is exactly what I was looking. I changed all the Sets to Subs and now it works perfectly!